# How do I split header values and convert them in different columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data which looks like this
[image]

However I need to separate the header values and convert them into three different column and it should look like the following.

[image]

What is the best method to achieve this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math
import os

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/callmedemi/AMPSE/main/machinepara1_gm_m1.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(url, encoding='latin')
print(dataset)
dataset1 = dataset.columns
print(dataset1)
```

The answer looks like this:

```
        wn   ...  leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 2 "lp" 4e-05 "wp" 0.0002 ) (S)
0  0.000005  ...                                       6.773000e-21                  
1  0.000008  ...                                       6.774000e-21                  
2  0.000010  ...                                       6.775000e-21                  
3  0.000013  ...                                       6.776000e-21                  
4  0.000015  ...                                       6.776000e-21                  

[5 rows x 251 columns]
Index(['wn ',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 0 "lp" 1.5e-05 "wp" 0.00012 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 0 "lp" 1.5e-05 "wp" 0.00014 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 0 "lp" 1.5e-05 "wp" 0.00016 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 0 "lp" 1.5e-05 "wp" 0.00018 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 0 "lp" 1.5e-05 "wp" 0.0002 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 0 "lp" 2.125e-05 "wp" 0.00012 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 0 "lp" 2.125e-05 "wp" 0.00014 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 0 "lp" 2.125e-05 "wp" 0.00016 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 0 "lp" 2.125e-05 "wp" 0.00018 ) (S)',
       ...
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 2 "lp" 3.375e-05 "wp" 0.00012 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 2 "lp" 3.375e-05 "wp" 0.00014 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 2 "lp" 3.375e-05 "wp" 0.00016 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 2 "lp" 3.375e-05 "wp" 0.00018 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 2 "lp" 3.375e-05 "wp" 0.0002 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 2 "lp" 4e-05 "wp" 0.00012 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 2 "lp" 4e-05 "wp" 0.00014 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 2 "lp" 4e-05 "wp" 0.00016 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 2 "lp" 4e-05 "wp" 0.00018 ) (S)',
       'leafValue( OP("/I0/M1" "gm") "Vbias" 2 "lp" 4e-05 "wp" 0.0002 ) (S)'],
      dtype='object', length=251)
```

If you see the for each "lp", "wp" gives five different values and for each "Vbias"(range:0-2) there are five different lp values. The header is the main issue here as I can't extract the header.

What I want to do is, extract "Vbias", "lp" and "wp" from the header for each of "gm" values and place them in corresponding columns. The picture files are just for a better understanding, the real CSV file is in the code.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to read the CSV file from the provided URL, I got and encoding error, so I first needed to an argument to specify a valid encoding to be used.

Then, since the column headers seem to be unusable and we know the exact names we want to put there, we may simply replace the data frame columns names with our own list:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/callmedemi/AMPSE/main/trial.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(url, encoding='latin')

# remove imported column headers
df = dataset[1:]  

# and define new ones, based on our knowledge of the data
df.columns = ['wm', 'gm', 'Vbias', 'lp', 'wp' ] 

print(df)
```

Result:

```
         wm            gm         Vbias            lp            wp
1  0.000007  4.250000e-08  4.350000e-08  4.440000e-08  4.540000e-08
2  0.000010  5.480000e-08  5.580000e-08  5.670000e-08  5.770000e-08
3  0.000013  6.710000e-08  6.810000e-08  6.900000e-08  7.000000e-08
4  0.000015  7.940000e-08  8.040000e-08  8.130000e-08  8.230000e-08
```

Comment: I think I haven't been able to give a clear picture of the issue. The header here is not gibberish. I need the values from Vbias, lp and wp from the header which changes. So wp changes five times for each lp and lp changes five times for each vbias and their corresponding values are written in the output.  If you compare the Vbias, lp and wp, you will see they are the values mentioned in the header and not the gm values.

Comment: I see. What is the expected pattern in the header? What parts do change in that text?

Comment: So for Vbias = 0, lp = 1.5e-05, wp changes from 0.00012 to 0.00020 as (0.00012,0.00014,0.00016,0.00018,0.00020). And for each lp change Vbias also changes from 0 to 2.